# Jenkins Declarative pipeline: scan logs and fail the job if it has a failure message

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I need to scan the Jenkins logs and if it has something like "Failed" in the logs. Jenkins should not continue and mark the job as failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `log-parser` plugin may be what you need.

It parses the console log generated by the Jenkins build.

You have two useful options:

- "Mark build Unstable on Warning" option: check to have parsed warnings mark the build 'unstable'.
- "Mark build Failed on Error" option : check to have parsed errors mark the build 'failed'.

Take a look at: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin

For declarative pipeline, try:

```
step([$class: 'LogParserPublisher', failBuildOnError: true, parsingRulesPath: '<parser rule file>', useProjectRule: false])
```

Comment: Is there any way I can do it through the declarative pipeline something like this : script{
                        if( manager.logContains('.*failed patching.*') ){
                            error("Failure")
                        }
                     } . This is not working. I need some function that scan logs in declarative pipeline.

Comment: ```node {
echo "test failed patching"
   stage('test'){
        step([$class: 'LogParserPublisher', failBuildOnError: true, parsingRulesPath: 'rule', useProjectRule: false])    
   }
}``` 
Rule file text : error /*failed patching*/ 
I expect job to be failed. Any suggestion why it is not failing?

Answer (score 2):

With findText from the [Text Finder plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/text-finder/) it is easy.

```
                // stop if failure found
                findText alsoCheckConsoleOutput: true, notBuiltIfFound: true, regexp: "${KEY_ERROR_MSG}"

                if (currentBuild.result == 'NOT_BUILT') {
                    error("${KEY_ERROR_MSG}")
                }
```

Note that this can be run direct in stages, meaning you don't need to wait for all stages to run this.

Example how to search an error message, mark the step as failed and set the build to unstable (I used this to check connection problems with ftp Publisher):

```
    // Search console log for error text and set build unstable if found
    findText(textFinders: [
         textFinder(
             regexp: 'ERROR: Exception when publishing', 
             alsoCheckConsoleOutput: true, 
             buildResult: 'UNSTABLE'
         )
    ])  
    script {
        if (currentBuild.result == 'UNSTABLE') {
            catchError(buildResult: 'UNSTABLE', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
                error("FTP publishing build artifacts failed") 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I prefer this plugin over log-parser because I find it more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

I got it failing with above proposal by having like this in parser config:

```
# ERRORS
error /make to fail/
```

And in Jenkins pipeline like this:

```
node ('') {
    try {
        node {
            echo 'make to fail'
        }
    } finally {
        node {
            step([$class: 'LogParserPublisher', failBuildOnError: true, parsingRulesPath: '/opt/jenkins/log_parsers/log_parser', useProjectRule: false])
        }
    }
}
```

Anyway have not find way to get build 'UNSTABLE' by using something like this in parser config:

```
# WARNINGS
warning /make to unstable/
```

Anyone having ideas how to achieve that?

Comment: 'UNSTABLE' thing seems to be taken care by: failBuildOnError: true

Comment: I suggest to edit the original answer if you want to add information.